# keepalive timeout on unix/windows

Tags: windows, unix, tcp

What is the error returned on aix/linux when a connection breaks down due to keepalive activity? Is it a unique error code which can be distinguished from other socket errors?

On windows this can be either [WSAECONNRESET or WSAENETRESET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is there a way to differentiate the error due to keepalive activity when WSAECONNRESET is returned?

> WSAECONNRESET
>   10054
>   Connection reset by peer.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to differentiate the error due to keepalive activity when WSAECONNRESET is returned ?

No. The underlying condition is a 'connection reset' in all cases.